# How to use a rule inside another rule on pyke?

Tags: nested, rule, pyke

I am using pyke3-1.1.1, how do you write a rule whose 'assert' contains another rule defined before? I want to do this in the forward chaining type.

Example:

Rule1
foreach
questions.test_question(True)
Assert
Python print("rule 1 called")

Rule2
foreach
questions.test_question2(True)
assert
(How to call rule1 here?)